# Android can't access services hosted on my own LAN

Tags: wi-fi, networking, lan

My girlfriends Sony Xperia X cannot currently access any internal services on my network.

access to the external internet is fine.

I have a very simple home network. single wireless AP running a single 192.168.1.0/24 network with DHCP provided by the router.

I have a ESXi host with a variety of services running. Included amongst that is a media centre running SABNZBD/SONARR & Couchpotato.

I set my girlfriend up with NZB360 a few weeks ago so she could control the media downloads. This has stopped working.

I have tested NZB360 from my own HTC M7 and it works fine. I have also tested all web services from the hosting machine and other devices across the network. All systems are up and working as expected. Attempting to access the web services via Chrome does not work (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

On my GF's phone I have installed fing, on running a scan on the network I can see all the devices on the network, but running a service scan against the windows box hosting the media centre I see zero services listed. Running the same scan in fing on my own phone shows ~15 ports open.

I've installed a simple shell on the GF's phone and IFCONFIG shows a proper network configuration. Ping responds as expected.

I can access my own phone from other devices on the network, and it responds to ping/icmp. Hers does not.

To all intents and purposes it looks like a firewall or equivalent is running on her phone, however she it not aware of any changes made in the couple of weeks since NZB360 was working.

Any thoughts?

Note : Android v6.0.1, no outstanding updates. Several listed over the past few weeks.

Comment: My only suggestion beyond going through her phone to check the wifi settings for a proxy/firewall is to see what differences over the wire there are between your phone and hers. Use wireshark or Charles or other proxy man-in-the-middle program to see what if anything is different - especially with a standard web interface running on you media server.